# Restricted version fo CNF-SAT

Tags: np-complete, satisfiability, decision-problem

Given formula $\phi$ on CNF-form in CNF-SAT. Clauses can be arbitrarily long. The problem is NP-complete and it is also given that part of the problem is that a variable can occur many times in a formula.

Another problem $CNF_3$ is introduced. Each variable can at most occur **three** times, with a given formula. This problem is NP-complete.

Problem: Decide if this formula is satisfiable or not. Give a method translating any $\phi$ to a $CNF_3$ formula $\psi$ such that $\phi$ is satisfiable if and only if $\psi$ is.

Following hints are given:

- Introduce new variables in $\phi$
- Variables $a$ and $b$ are equivalent if $(a\lor \lnot b )\land (\lnot a\lor b)$

I have trouble starting this task. Any help necessary is appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried already and why didn't it work out as wanted? Hint: For a variable $x$ that occurs $n$ times in $\phi$, introduce new variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ in $\psi$.

Comment: I know for sure through CNF-SAT that the formula should be with conjunctions and disjunctions where each clause has to fulfill the conditions given in the task (that is $CNF_x$). Other than that I really don't know how to begin with the problem. With your comment i believe that for each variable $x_i$ can at most occur three times. Once this condition is reached, add $x_i$ to $\psi$

Comment: @Gaste Make an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi$ be an arbitrary $\mathrm{CNF}$ formula. The idea is to start with $\psi := \phi$ and then replace each variable in $\psi$ that occurs more than three times by distinct copies that are logically equivalent.

Lets consider each variable $x$ that occurs $n$ times in $\psi$. If $n$ is less or equal than $3$, the (syntactic) $\mathrm{CNF}_3$-condition is fulfilled for $x$ and we do not need to change $\psi$. So lets assume that $x$ occurs more than three times in $\psi$. We introduce $n$ new variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and replace the $i^{th}$ occurrence of $x$ in $\psi$ with the new variable $x_i$.

In order to have the property $\phi \in \mathrm{CNF} \iff \psi \in \mathrm{CNF}_3$, we need to add the condition that all $x_i$ must be equivalent, i.e.
\begin{align}
x_1 \iff x_2 \iff \ldots \iff x_n.
\end{align}

We can model a bi-implication $x_i \iff x_{i+1}$ like proposed in the hint with the two clauses
\begin{align}
  (x_{i} \lor \lnot x_{i+1}) \land (\lnot x_{i} \lor x_{i+1}).
\end{align}

Unfortunately, we cannot do this directly since doing so would cause each variable $x_i$ of the set $\{x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}\}$ to appear more than three times inside $\psi$:
\begin{align}
  (x_{i-1} \lor \lnot x_{i}) \land (\lnot x_{i-1} \lor x_{i}) \land (x_{i} \lor \lnot x_{i+1}) \land (\lnot x_{i} \lor x_{i+1})
\end{align}
Therefore, for each inner bi-implication $x_i \iff x_{i+1}$ above ($i \in \{2, \ldots, n-2\}$), we introduce a new variable $x_{i,i+1}$ that acts as a bridge between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$:
\begin{align}
  x_i \iff x_{i,i+1} \iff x_{i+1}.
\end{align}

Each bridging variable $x_{i,i+1}$ occurs twice inside $\psi$. Furthermore, each new variable $x_i$ occurs three times inside $\psi$, namely

- once inside clause where it replaces $x$, and
- twice inside the clause $x_i \iff x_{i,i+1}$.

Therefore, the new formula $\psi$ fulfills the syntatic $\mathrm{CNF}_3$ condition after the replacement.